# Referencing a class variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class with several variables inside

```py
class myClass():
   def __init__(self):
      self.first = ""
      self.second = ""
      self.third = ""
```

Ok, so if I then initialize a variable to that class, I understand that I can easily reference or set any of those class variables like this

```
myClassVar = myClass()

myClassVar.first = "foo"
myClassVar.second = "bar"
```

What I'm wanting to know is, what if the class variable I want to set is itself determined by another variable.  for instance, if I looped through a list ["first", "second", "third"], is there any way to reference those class variables like this:

```
varList = ["first", "second", "third"]
for item in varList:
   myClass.item = "whatever I want to set it to"
```

Something like what I just did will result in "myClass has no 'item' member"

Comment: Isn't the effect the same as using a dictionary where varlist defines the keys?

Comment: You rarely initialize attributes like this. Define `__init__` to take values as arguments to set the attributes for you, and call it as `obj = MyClass("foo", 'bar", "baz)`.

Comment: Very important terminology note: you aren't talking about *class variables*, you are talking about *instance variables*

Comment: with `myClass.item` you're assigning something to the class itself. Apparently you wanted to instantiate the class first, then assign something to the instance. `myClassVar = myClass()`

Comment: @chepner agreed, I don't initialize the values the way I did in my example.  I actually initialize them as you describe.  I tried to simplify my example, because what I'm actually doing is trying to set and get those values later on based on other processed information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`setattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr). It takes the attribute name as string:

```py
class myClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.first = ""
        self.second = ""
        self.third = ""

varList = ["first", "second", "third"]

myClassVar = myClass()
for item in varList:
    setattr(myClassVar, item, "whatever I want to set it to")

print(myClassVar.first)
print(myClassVar.second)
```

output:

```
whatever I want to set it to
whatever I want to set it to
```

---

> Something like what I just did will result in "myClass has no 'item'
> member"

That shouldn't happen if you're working with normal attributes. Python allows you to dynamically assign new attributes just like you did. But now `myClassVar` has `item` attribute in its namespace.

If you use slots for example, it prevents you from doing so:

```py
class myClass:
    __slots__ = ("first", "second", "third")

    def __init__(self):
        self.first = ""
        self.second = ""
        self.third = ""


varList = ["first", "second", "third"]
myClassVar = myClass()
for item in varList:
    myClassVar.item = "whatever I want to set it to"
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for.  Confirmed that the getattr and setattr are doing what I want